# Input string was not in a correct format when get data from class in html page

Tags: c#, asp.net

**BorrowerInfoFullDetails.cs**

```
public class BorrowerInfoFullDetails  
{  
  public decimal TotalLoanAmount { get; set; }  
}
```

**Borrower.aspx.cs**

```
namespace MFCloudAspx
{
 public partial class Borrower : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
   public BorrowerInfoFullDetails objBorrowerInfoFullDetails;
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      objBorrowerInfoFullDetails = new BorrowerInfoFullDetails();
      objBorrowerInfoFullDetails.TotalLoanAmount = 25000;
   }
 }
}
```

**Borrower.aspx**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <h2>Rs. 
<%=string.Format("{0,N}",objBorrowerInfoFullDetails.TotalLoanAmount) %></h2>
<h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></i>
<br>
  Loan Amount</h3>
 </div>
```

**Error** 
    <%=string.Format("{0,N}",objBorrowerInfoFullDetails.TotalLoanAmount) %>
    Input string was not in a correct format.
**I Want value print value 25,000**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need colon instead of comma. Try this:-

```
<%=string.Format("{0:N}",objBorrowerInfoFullDetails.TotalLoanAmount) %></h2>
```

Check [Formatting Numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687.aspx) fields List.